# how to get location using Latitude and Longitude in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can i get location address using  Latitude and Longitude in c#.Please Help

Comment: Hi ,Given below is sample code for get address using Latitude and Longitude

Comment: You should mention that your answer relies on the JSON.Net parser - install it via NuGet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this code ,I hope this will help you.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string strLatitude = " 13.00";
        string strLongitude = "80.25";
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        string Url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + strLatitude + "," + strLongitude + "&sensor=true";
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        Console.Read();

static void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    var getResult = e.Result;
        JObject parseJson = JObject.Parse(getResult);
        var getJsonres = parseJson["results"][0];
        var getJson = getJsonres["address_components"][1];
        var getAddress = getJson["long_name"];
        string Address = getAddress.ToString();
```

}

Comment: Hai prabha.Really this helped.thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a web service like [Google Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) or [Bing Maps REST Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx).