# How to get zipcode from lat lon in .net

Tags: .net, google-maps

Is there any way to get zipcodes for particular area using lat lon? I am getting the address but not zipcode . 
I am refereing this link [how to get location using Latitude and Longitude in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732721/how-to-get-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-windows-phone-8) to get the address from lat lon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method gets the postal code using the Google Maps API.

```
string GetPostalCode(string lat, string lng)
{
    string postalCode = "";
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng +"&sensor=true");
    var components = xml["GeocodeResponse"]["result"].ChildNodes;
    foreach (XmlElement x in components)
    {
        if (x.Name == "address_component" && x["type"].InnerText == "postal_code")
        {
            postalCode = x["long_name"].InnerText;
            break;
        }
    }
    return postalCode;
}
```